# getting permission denied error when issuing oozie commands

Tags: hadoop, oozie

have built oozie  with  mvn clean package -DskipTests -Phadoop-2 -Dassembly.ignorePermissions assembly:single

[image: permission denied error]

Comment: Are you providing code, data, or something else that users would like to copy and paste? Please consider typing or pasting that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

please ignore,  missed out  the adminusers.txt in conf

just mentioning the user name in the adminusers.txt have solved the problem